# 2FA on Exchange OWA w/ mobile phones?

Tags: authentication, exchange

Does anyone have any experience with enabling 2factor authentication on a public facing OWA (exchange webmail)? I would like to enable this however i'm concerned as to how it would affect mobile devices from accessing mail.

Or put a different way: "which mobile Exchange clients support 2FA?" ?

Comment: I'm wondering if Azure MFA (formerly PhoneFactor) might fit the bill? - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Duo Security supports [two-factor authentication for OWA](https://www.duosecurity.com/docs/owa). I'm not sure if you're also asking about the built-in clients for the various Activesync-capable devices...

Can you clarify?

Comment: yes i'm referring to built in clients on Android and Iphone devices that do activesync natively.